# Why is my django application on cpanel only recognising the root url and not any other url after the root url?

Tags: python, django, cpanel, django-urls, django-deployment

I recently deployed my Django application on a subdomain through Cpanel. However, when I try to access the application, only the root url is working. Any other address is not being sent. In the browser, anything after the / of the root url is grayed out and the logs of the application also suggest they are not receiving the entire address. I have attached screenshots herein for clarity. Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Result after accessing any other address]
[image: applogs]

Comment: Can you share your `settings.py`? Maybe a misconfiguration in the `allowed_hosts` variable.

Comment: @DeusDev. Failed to figure out how to attach an image in here but this is how my ALLOWED_HOSTS look like.

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['api.chimombedesigns.co.zw', 'www.api.chimombedesigns.co.zw']